# Call PHP Function In Smarty

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

Can someone show or tell me how to call the php function below to get the ratings for each movie in smarty as i'm new to php.

```
public function getRating($movieid){
    $movieid = mysql_real_escape_string($movieid);
    $average = 0;
    $e = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(`rating`) as average FROM movie_ratings WHERE movieid='$movieid'") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($e)>0){
      extract(mysql_fetch_array($e));
    }
    return $average;
}
```

I've tried this but it don't work could some tell me what i am doing wrong please.

```
if (isset($movieid)); {
    $rating = $movie->getRating($movieid);
    $smarty->assign("rating",$rating); 
}
```

The error i get is

```
Undefined variable: movieid
```

Comment: I get a Undefined variable: movieid

Comment: remove semicolon from if (isset($movieid)); ...!

Comment: I did that but now get a `Undefined variable: rating` any help how you call it?

Comment: On this `$smarty->assign("rating",$rating); `